# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'map'

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am running a simple program from GitHub (https://github.com/tyleryasaka/weatherman).

It gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Humxa/Desktop/weatherman-master/weatherman.py", line 39, in <module>
        actual = learn.predict(classifier, trainings, tests)
      File "C:\Users\Humxa\Desktop\weatherman-master\learn.py", line 11, in predict
        fit = classifier.fit(data, target)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 739, in fit
        X_idx_sorted=X_idx_sorted)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 122, in fit
        X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csc")
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 382, in check_array
        array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
    TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'map'
```

Comment: Tell us about the inputs to this code, which I'm guessing are `data` and `target`

Comment: here it is basically it is json data    def getFeatures(sample):
    return sample['features']

def getClassification(sample):
    return sample['classification']

def predict(classifier, trainings, tests):
    data = map(getFeatures, trainings)
    target = map(getClassification, trainings)
    testData = map(getFeatures, tests)
    fit = classifier.fit(data, target)
    return fit.predict(testData)

Comment: Are you running this in PY3?  There `map` has to be wrapped in `list()` to be evaluated

Comment: Yes I am running pyhton 3 how to wrap can you guide me a bit ?

Comment: `list(map(....))`

Comment: Okay let me try that

Comment: Thank you you are genius :)